# Can the sum of $f(x)$ where $a<x<b$ be approximated to the area underneath?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

How to find the sum of a function within a given range? For example $\sum f(x)$ when $x$ varies from say $0$ to $1$?

My line of reasoning,

1. Divide the interval $(0,1)$ into small equal parts of length $dx$ and assume (approximate) that the function has a constant value $f(x_c)$ in that interval $dx$ ($x_0$ is either at the beginning of $dx$ or at the end of $dx$).
2. Now the sum of the function in this interval $dx$ is just $f(x_c) + f(x_c) +.... f(x_c)$ ((i.e.) add $f(x_c)$, $dx$ times) which means the sum of $f(x)$ in the interval $dx$ is approximated to $(f(x_0) \times dx)$ that is, Sum $\approx$ area of the rectangle with height $f(x_0)$ and breadth $dx$.
3. Move on to the next interval $dx$ and do the same and finally add all these small areas.

So in conclusion the objective, of finding the sum of $f(x)$ in the interval $0 <x< 1$ is approximately equal to the area underneath it?

Is this correct or have I gone wrong somewhere?

**Edit:**

Context: I'm learning continuous probability distributions and am trying to reason out why area underneath = the probability to be in between the given range (as a sum of all probabilities).

I understand there's no meaning in the phrase "Sum of f(x)" but that's exactly what we are trying to get around with continuous probability distributions aren't we?

Comment: What does "sum of a function" even mean? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: You’re basically describing a Riemann sum. It turns into an integral when $dx\to 0$.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Hmm, yeah. I'm learning continuous probability distributions and trying to reason out why area underneath = the probability to be in between the given range

Comment: @AravindhVasu You seem to be doing a pretty good job reasoning out why integrals are areas and probabilities.

Comment: @EthanBolker So is my line of reasoning correct ? Is that how we construct a continuous probability distribution in the first place ?

Comment: You're not "constructing a continuous probability distribution". Such a distribution is just a positive function that encloses a total area of $1$ over the $x$-axis.  The probability of a subset is the area over it. Single points have probability $0$ since the line above a point has area $0$, but a small interval of length $L$ about  point $x$ has probability approximately  $f(x)\times L$. You never "add up all the values of $f$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition about summing up infinitesimal probabilities is correct. The values of the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) $f_X$ of a continuous random variable $X$ are not actual probabilities, though - the density function is by definition the *derivative* of the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). So your observation follows from the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). That is, $$P(a<X<b)=\int_a^b f_X(x) dx.$$ Remember that $f_X(x)$ is not the same thing as $P(X=x)$. It's better to think of it as $$f_X(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{P(x<X<x+h)}h.$$